# Destructor execution order list

Tags: c++, destructor

Can you create destructor execution order list from this code?

```
Ap1(1);
int main()
{
   A* p2= new A(2);
   {
      Ap3(3);
   }
   Ap4(4);
   Ap5(5);
   delete p2;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Homework? What did you try till now?

Answer (score 1):

It looks alot like homework, so I will instead of giving you the exact answer, which you should easily be able to do, I will tell you a simple way of figuring out. Create a simple class that outputs on construction and destruction and simply read the output.

I have made a simple sample here: http://ideone.com/wbMeyE

```
class A
{
public:
    A(const std::string& name) : name(name) { std::cout << "Constructing: " << name << '\n'; };
    ~A() { std::cout << "Destructing: " << name << '\n'; };

private:
    std::string name;
};
```

Comment: Currently i don't have access to compiler and i didn't know about this site. This is knowledge needed to incoming exam. Thanks a lot

Comment: Did you look for a(n online) compiler?

Comment: I was looking for execution order. But online compiler solve my problem and i didn't know that exists.